# str to dict in python, but maintain the sequence of json attributes

Tags: python, json

I've tried ast.literal_eval and json.loads but both of these, doesn't maintain the sequence of json attributes when a string is provided. Please see the following example -

## String before providing it to json.loads -

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "i": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "strList": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "strMap": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "p2": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "i": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "p3": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "i": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "p4": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "i": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "p3": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "i": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "p4": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "i": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "b": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "classnames": {
        "rootNode": {
            "classname": "com.agent.Person"
        },
        "p2": {
            "classname": "com.agent.Person2",
            "p3": {
                "classname": "com.agent.Person3",
                "p4": {
                    "classname": "com.agent.Person4"
                }
            }
        },
        "p3": {
            "classname": "com.agent.Person3",
            "p4": {
                "classname": "com.agent.Person4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## String after providing it to json.loads -

```
{
    'classnames': {
        'p2': {
            'classname': 'com.agent.Person2',
            'p3': {
                'classname': 'com.agent.Person3',
                'p4': {
                    'classname': 'com.agent.Person4'
                }
            }
        },
        'p3': {
            'classname': 'com.agent.Person3',
            'p4': {
                'classname': 'com.agent.Person4'
            }
        },
        'rootNode': {
            'classname': 'com.agent.Person'
        }
    },
    'properties': {
        'b': {
            'required': True,
            'type': 'boolean'
        },
        'i': {
            'type': 'integer'
        },
        'name': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'p2': {
            'items': {
                'properties': {
                    'i': {
                        'type': 'integer'
                    },
                    'name': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    },
                    'p3': {
                        'properties': {
                            'i': {
                                'type': 'integer'
                            },
                            'name': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            },
                            'p4': {
                                'properties': {
                                    'i': {
                                        'type': 'integer'
                                    },
                                    'name': {
                                        'type': 'string'
                                    }
                                },
                                'type': 'object'
                            }
                        },
                        'type': 'object'
                    }
                },
                'type': 'object'
            },
            'type': 'array'
        },
        'p3': {
            'items': {
                'properties': {
                    'i': {
                        'type': 'integer'
                    },
                    'name': {
                        'type': 'string'
                    },
                    'p4': {
                        'properties': {
                            'i': {
                                'type': 'integer'
                            },
                            'name': {
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        },
                        'type': 'object'
                    }
                },
                'type': 'object'
            },
            'type': 'array'
        },
        'strList': {
            'items': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'type': 'array'
        },
        'strMap': {
            'type': 'object'
        }
    },
    'type': 'array'
}
```

Can anyone please suggest an alternative or something in python which keeps the sequence of attributes as they are and convert the string into the python dictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered and usually do not need to be ordered. If you want this just for printing, consider using some custom `key` function for ordering the elements. Also, if you were inserting the elements into the dict in a loop, you could use `collections.OrderedDict`, but I don't think this will work for `json`.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to say'.

Comment: Actually I want the string to be converted to dictionary, but the keys should be in the same order as they are in the provided string. And in collections.OrderedDict, it doesn't take string as the input i.e. the whole string, which can be converted to dict.

Comment: Just for the record, the json specification explicitly mentions that "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs", so you should not need to care about ordering here. What's your use case exactly ?

Comment: As I mentioned in question, I've a json string, and ast.literal_eval and json.loads converts it to dict but orders the keys alphabetically. Hence I'm not able to maintain the sequence, which I need it. But the answer provided completely fits in the use case mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As tobias_k has said, python dictionaries are unordered, so you'll lose any order information as soon as you load your data into one.

You can, however, load your JSON string into a OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

json.loads(your_json_string, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

This method [is mentioned in the `json` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: Lovely, completely fits in, sorry for the dumb question. I'm very new to python, and after searching a lot, I couldn't find the answer.